# Network, cluster & virtual partitions

Tags: java, jboss, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, partitioning

I'm trying to design a distributed JBoss application, and this afternoon I overheard some co-workers talking about the CAP theorem, and in particular the "P" (partitioning) portion of it. They were talking about how it applied to various partition types, namely cluster partitions, network partitions and virtual partitions.

My *understanding* of a network partition is that its an intentional design to fragment a network into 2+ isolated parts, so that it can handle an outage of one or more of the individual fragments. How do cluster partitions fit into this model (and thus relate back to CAP), and what is a "virtual" partition?!?

I'm wondering if I need to take any of these into consideration when clustering my JBoss app, and if I do, where to start with such considerations. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

According to `CAP` theorem you can't achieve all three of `C`onsistency, `A`vailability and `P`artition tolerance *at one moment*.

My interpretation is that *it doesn't mean your app necessarily loses `A` forever if you choose `C+P`*. An app can be designed to have any pair of `CAP` at different moments. And you have to decide which pair of `CAP` you want to have most times.

In context of a JBoss cluster you can setup an isolated stand-by secondary partition to swap it instead of your primary partition during upgrades/maintenance works. This way you mostly have `C+A` without `P` because you are not using both partitions during main time. Now you decide it's time to upgrade your app, what options you have? You can temporarily change either `C` or `A` for `P`. That is, you can swap partitions (lose `C`) or bring the whole cluster down (lose `A`).

Of course, you can choose other combinations of `CAP` for main time. It depends on what SLA is OK for you app. More popular ones are `C+A` and `A+P`.

Answer (score 0):

The partition tolerance in CAP theorem is a theoretical concept, not a concrete one.  It refers to the ability for the overall system to handle communication failures. It does not refer to any deliberate separation of nodes.

[CAP theorem itself says, from a web service perspective](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/tds/papers/Gilbert/Brewer2.pdf):

> In a network subject to communication failures, it is impossible for any web service to implement an atomic read/write shared memory that guarantees a response to every request.

Note that for web services backed by a database, you don't actually need to worry about CAP theorem, since you aren't trying to implement any shared memory; the database does it for you. If you maintain any live state in your application, you *do* need to worry about CAP theorem, because that state represents some read/write memory you want to maintain atomically (`c`onsistently), reliably (`a`vailably), and in the face of network failures between nodes (`p`artition tolerant).

If you are backed by a database on more than one node, the database itself has to deal with CAP theorem. Any HA solution deployed makes different tradeoffs in order to handle communication failures.  For example, MongoDB replica sets trade off availability by forcing any node not connected to a majority of nodes to give up its master status. Make sure you understand what your database does in adverse conditions, and make sure they match up with your application's requirements.